# Marketing Cloud Install Process

Tags: marketing-cloud, appexchange

We are currently developing an application(**Enhanced functionality - OAuth2.0**) for the Salesforce Marketing Cloud which can be installed via AppExchange.

I'm a bit struggling to find the documentation which will explain to me what is actually happen when a user is pressing "Get It Now" -> "Install from Salesforce Marketing Cloud".

I mean what are the endpoints that invoked on our side and how
actually the loop is closed? What is the indication for Salesforce that the install process completed successfully?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoints are defined when creating the Installed Package.  These are the endpoints that will be called when a Login event occurs (ie get it now or click from the Installed Package dropdown).

Marketing Cloud will essentially bring up an iFrame with your configured Login endpoint as the url.  You will get a JWT providing information about the Marketing Cloud instance, the User, the Rest endpoint and token information.  What your application does with this information and what sort of UI you display in this frame is up to your application's needs.

There is no indication to Marketing Cloud that anything succeeded nor a closing of the loop.  The package will be installed into the MID and your UI can be brought back up at any time in the Installed Packages dropdown with that MID (again triggering the Login call to your application inside of a frame).  It will keep sending a new JWT each time which is intended for your capture so you may store needed information.

Comment: Thank you Mike! I understood this flow for the JWT. My question was specifically about the "Enhanced Functionality" Installed Package - This package is using the OAuth2.0 flow and not the SSO - JWT. Does it behaves the same? Because in the OAuth flow the [first call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/authorization-code.htm)
seems like it have to be triggered by us and not automatically sent by SFMC.